# TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I get the errors below when loading a model in a separate script to make inferences. I'm able to train and save the model without a problem. My model is almost identical to the one in the Keras documentation **HERE: https://keras.io/examples/nlp/pretrained_word_embeddings/**

```
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor("model_2/embedding_1/embedding_lookup_ragged/embedding_lookup/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 100), dtype=float32), row_splits=Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64))


TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.ragged.ragged_tensor.RaggedTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor("model_2/embedding_1/embedding_lookup_ragged/embedding_lookup/Identity_1:0", shape=(None, 100), dtype=float32), row_splits=Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

my training session runs without a hitch. I'm even able to make predictions in the same training session.

I'm loading my model as follows:

```
model = load_model('saved_model', compile = False)
```

I'm running Keras 2.6.0

the full call back is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 549, in make_tensor_proto
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 549, in <listcomp>
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py", line 86, in as_bytes
    raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(None, 100), dtype=float32), row_splits=Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\####\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14488/2463106565.py", line 20, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model', compile = False)

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\save.py", line 205, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 143, in load
    keras_loader.finalize_objects()

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 644, in finalize_objects
    self._reconstruct_all_models()

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 663, in _reconstruct_all_models
    self._reconstruct_model(model_id, model, layers)

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 708, in _reconstruct_model
    created_layers) = functional_lib.reconstruct_from_config(

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1283, in reconstruct_from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1231, in process_node
    output_tensors = layer(input_tensors, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\yanie\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 976, in __call__
    return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1114, in _functional_construction_call
    outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 848, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 888, in _infer_output_signature
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 1232, in call
    outputs = tf.tensordot(inputs, self.kernel, [[rank - 1], [0]])

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 206, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 5036, in tensordot
    a = ops.convert_to_tensor(a, name="a")

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\trace.py", line 163, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1566, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 346, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 271, in constant
    return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 288, in _constant_impl
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(

  File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\envs\nn_deep_learning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 551, in make_tensor_proto
    raise TypeError("Failed to convert object of type %s to Tensor. "

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.ragged.ragged_tensor.RaggedTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(None, 100), dtype=float32), row_splits=Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Comment: The code given in the link is working fine using `Tensorflow 2.6` and `keras 2.6.` Could you please provide some more details to assess this issue like which tensorflow and python version are you using and if you could share minimal reproducible code to replicate the error. Please try running your code again by upgrading the TensorFlow version.